Dynamically implementing a statically defined interface on an F# type with functions statically defined on that type
I have a use case that looks something like the following:
type Event =
    | EventA
    | EventB

type IState =
    abstract member HandleEvent: Event -> IState

type ExampleState =
    { ListOfSomething: int list }

    interface IState with
        member this.HandleEvent event =
            match event with
            | EventA -> this
            | EventB -> this

let functionThatUsesIState (state: IState) (listOfStates: list<IState>) =
    state :: listOfStates

The reason an interface is used because I need to have a collection that contains all of the states, and thus, I need a single type to make the collection homogeneous. In this example, I've shown a list<IState> for simplicity. In my actual application, it is a Map<string, IState>.

The issue I have with this method is that it requires users of functionThatUsesIState to create a type and then implement interfaces. This is okay-ish, but I'd prefer a more functional approach such that functionThatUsesIState (or a function that wraps it) doesn't take an interface but instead just takes a value of type 'T and then a function that processes 'T.
For example, instead of using an interface at the high-level, I could just define:
type HowIdLikeToDefineState =
    { ListOfSomething: int list }

let howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent (state: HowIdLikeToDefineState) (event: Event) =
    match event with
    | EventA -> state
    | EventB -> state

This could work if I did something like:
let functionThatUsesState (state: 'T) (listOfStates: list<'T>) =
    state :: listOfStates

This "works", but it is no good for my application. What I really need is a listOfStates where 'T is not always (almost never) the same between the elements.

So, one way I have thought of is that it would be great if I could use howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent to dynamically implement IState on HowIdLikeToDefineState.
Because then I could do something like:
let highLevelFunctionThatUsesState (state: 'T) (eventHandler: 'T -> Event -> 'T) (listOfStates: list<IState>) =
    // "dynamically" implement IState on 'T using eventHandler as the implementation of HandleEvent
    let dynamicIStateBasedOnT = ...
    // pass this to functionThatUsesIState
    functionThatUsesIState dynamicIStateBasedOnT listOfStates

This seems like it might be possible in F# because of type extensions, object expressions, and reflection, but I haven't been able to concoct something. My best effort is:
let DynamicState =
    { new IState with
        member this.HandleEvent event = howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent this event }

which obviously doesn't work but gets the idea across. I don't know how to "attach" an interface implementation to an existing type dynamically. I don't even know if it's possible. I also tried:
let DynamicState =
    { new HowIdLikeToDefineState with
        interface IState with
            member this.HandleEvent event = howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent this event }

which also doesn't work since the type after new must be an interface for object expressions.


How can I solve this particular problem of taking an interface, a type, and a function on that type, and then dynamically implementing the interface on the type using the function, which obviously should match up to the interface's member definition(s)?

How else can I solve this problem? I effectively need a type Map<string, State<'T>> where 'T can vary. Obviously that can't happen, so how else can I solve this type of problem in F#? In my case, State<'T>'s members are effectively independent of 'T except for a member or two similar to the HandleEvent member in IState.


If there's something funky that C# can do here, I'm somewhat open to that, as I could make it a library (supposedly) sandwiched in between my F# code.

Okay, so this solution just occurred to me. I have confused myself, so I don't know whether this is all overwrought where I'm missing something much more simple or direct OR if there's some dumb reason why I missed this solution as the solution to such a problem as this.
Either way, here is at least a solution:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Original problem definitions                              //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

type Event =
    | EventA
    | EventB

type IState =
    abstract member HandleEvent: Event -> IState

type ExampleState =
    { ListOfSomething: int list }

    interface IState with
        member this.HandleEvent event =
            match event with
            | EventA -> this
            | EventB -> this

let functionThatUsesIState (state: IState) (listOfStates: list<IState>) =
    state :: listOfStates

type HowIdLikeToDefineState =
    { ListOfSomething: int list }

let howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent (state: HowIdLikeToDefineState) (event: Event) =
    match event with
    | EventA -> state
    | EventB -> state

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Here's where the solution to the question actually starts //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

type GenericState<'State> =
    { Value: 'State
      HandleEvent: 'State -> Event -> 'State }

    interface IState with
        member this.HandleEvent event = { this with Value = this.HandleEvent this.Value event }

let highLevelFunctionThatUsesState (initialState: 'T) (eventHandler: 'T -> Event -> 'T) (listOfStates: list<IState>) : list<IState> =
    // There's no need to cast to the interface here, but it's done
    // for clarity
    let genericState =
        { Value = initialState
          HandleEvent = eventHandler } :> IState
    functionThatUsesIState genericState listOfStates

// Usage
highLevelFunctionThatUsesState {ListOfSomething = []} howIdLikeToDefineHandleEvent []

I'm still curious about how others view this solution and if there's something more simple. I suppose this is what people mean by record of functions, but in this case, it's working in tandem with the interface.
